# Different loops in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, sorting

I've menu with urls: 
-sitename.com/popular
-sitename.com/toprated

I want to do sth like that:

if url = sitename.com/popular show loop popular, elseif url = sitename.com/toprated show loop toprated, else normal loop

How should code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [strpos()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp) and [$_SERVER[]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#111471)

Here is example:

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if(strpos($path, '/popular')) {
        // your first loop
    } elseif(strpos($path, '/toprated')) {
        // your second loop
    }
?>
```

Hope this will help you